# TeamCity & mocha-phantomjs: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require

Tags: javascript, teamcity, node-modules, mocha-phantomjs

I need to run JS tests on CI server. Testing framework is mocha.
I've found `mocha-phantomjs` but it gives me output like this:

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require at
>   c:/w1/-----/---/Tests/RestApiTests/BasicTests.js:1

When I changed reporter to 'teamcity' the output was like this:

> The Teamcity reporter was moved to a package named
>   mocha-teamcity-reporter
>   (https://npmjs.org/package/mocha-teamcity-reporter). Unable to open
>   file 'teamcity'

And no instructions the way I can use it.

I have two `*.js` files with tests, which has to be tested on CI server, with report of amount of tests passed/failed

Pretty new to JS, as well as to testing it, but I need to configure this tests in TeamCity, to have results on failed and passed tests.

Comment: This sounds like a CommonJS modules problem. From [`mocha-phantomjs` github issues](https://github.com/nathanboktae/mocha-phantomjs/issues/80): "The tests here are run within the browser which does not natively support modules. If you want to use a module pattern you will need to use a system like AMD or Browserify to support these within the browser context."